# Top-N ranking loss is difficult to optimize directly. Why?

Tags: neural-networks, optimization, ranking, autoencoders, recommender-system

[Variational Autoencoders for Collaborative Filtering](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.05814) paper tells:

> "Recommender systems are often evaluated using ranking-based measures, such as mean average precision and normalized discounted cumulative gain. Top-N ranking loss is difficult to optimize directly"

(Thanks to [whuber](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/919/whuber))
What kind of difficulty is there in optimizing them?
Can someone explain this with an example?

Comment: What's the top-N ranking loss? How is it defined?

Comment: @Sycorax 
 Top-N rank is a novel family of listwise Learning-to-Rank models for reliably recommending the N top-ranked items. But I don't know how the loss function is calculated for this Top-N ranking!

Comment: A good first step to understand why this function is hard optimize is learning what the function is.

Comment: @Sycorax if you could throw some light on that, it would be great...

Comment: A cursory search indicates many different ranking metrics or loss functions have been considered: see the abstract at https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10791-020-09377-x, for instance.  If you had included the *immediately preceding sentence* for context, things would be much clearer, so here it is (with added emphasis): "Recommender systems are often evaluated using ranking-based measures, **such as mean average precision and normalized discounted cumulative gain.**"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can find an answer in the abstract of "[Efficient Optimization for Rank-based Loss Functions](https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_cvpr_2018/papers/Mohapatra_Efficient_Optimization_for_CVPR_2018_paper.pdf)" by
Pritish Mohapatra Michal Rolínek, C.V. Jawahar, Vladimir Kolmogorov, M. Pawan Kumar. The abstract specifically names the two ranking-based measures as OP's quotation, average precision and normalized discounted cumulative gain.

> The accuracy of information retrieval systems is often
> measured using complex loss functions such as the average precision (AP) or the normalized discounted cumulative gain (NDCG). Given a set of positive and negative
> samples, the parameters of a retrieval system can be estimated by minimizing these loss functions. However, the
> non-differentiability and non-decomposability of these loss
> functions does not allow for simple gradient based optimization algorithms.

The paper develops these ideas in more detail.